# Significance of first two args for compile() python3

Tags: python

I am trying to broaden my understanding of various built in modules for python and I came across compile(). 
I've created a file named `program.py` which returns `print("hello")`. I intend on using (from what it seems) `compile()` to `exec` other programs within programs in the future.

**My question** is what are the significance of the first two arguments? I understand that the third can be one of three choices: `exec`, `eval` and `single`.

If anyone understands the `compile()` command please help me.

```
import program

compile('','','exec',flags=0,dont_inherit=False,optimize=-1)
# compile(source, filename, mode, flags=0, dont_inherit=False, optimize=-1) - are the args
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is the Python source to compile. The second is the filename to show in tracebacks.

```
>>> compile('foo', 'bar', 'exec')
<code object <module> at 0x7fb586b57ab0, file "bar", line 1>
>>> exec(compile('foo', 'bar', 'exec'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bar", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

1. source - can either be a Unicode string or a Latin-1 encoded string. i.e `compile('a + 5','', 'eval')`
2. The filename argument should give the file from which the code was
   read; pass some recognizable value if it wasn’t read from a file ('string' is commonly used).

So if you want to compile a file the first value will be an empty string, and the second value will specify the file name, and if you want to compile a string first value will be the string and second value will be an empty string.